# multidex class, class not found and keep crashing

Tags: android, android-studio

Well, i just added some gplay service dependencies and then i remove the dependency 
then this just got pop up

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.yukngaji.transaksi.sandbox, PID: 31258
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.app.yukngaji.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app.yukngaji.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.yukngaji.transaksi.sandbox-mHCwz7RvI-rgiO3KfiNFtQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.yukngaji.transaksi.sandbox-mHCwz7RvI-rgiO3KfiNFtQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7179)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app.yukngaji.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.yukngaji.transaksi.sandbox-mHCwz7RvI-rgiO3KfiNFtQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.yukngaji.transaksi.sandbox-mHCwz7RvI-rgiO3KfiNFtQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:47)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1120)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1115)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7179) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

i already added MultiDex Enable, androidx.multidex.blablabla, and try all thing on the internet, but it won't work

Comment: have you put it inside the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: what should i put on androidmanifest

Answer (score 0):

In your Application subclass override the **attachBaseContext** method and do this:

First you need to create a subclass of Application Class like this:
JAVA:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
//override this method
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this)
}
}
```

Kotlin:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
```

This should work

Comment: can you write it on java

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look and let me know what happens.

Comment: not it doesn't work, anyway i just clone again from my repisitory and it fixed